# Java Development in Dockerized environment: Debugging And hot code reload

Tags: java, debugging, docker

Hi I am new to Docker and would like to utilize it for java developing.

But I don't understand how to set up **hot code reload** or **debugging** of my application code for developing Java in a Docker container. E.g how to achieve "nice" development  like java supports with IDEs nowadays.

Is it really required to `docker build`do a new image to see the impact of changed code?

I have found the following links but they do not help me much.

- [Auto-reloading of code changes with Django development in Docker with Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022014/auto-reloading-of-code-changes-with-django-development-in-docker-with-gunicorn)
- [How to edit code in a Docker container in development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842920/how-to-edit-code-in-a-docker-container-in-development)
- http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html
- [What's the right way to setup a development environment on OS X with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090007/whats-the-right-way-to-setup-a-development-environment-on-os-x-with-docker)

Comment: Remove Docker from equation, how would you do it natively?

Comment: Well for example in vagrant these things work. However Docker would bee nice to ship the same environment to production. But if debugging and code reload do not work in the dev stage that would be a pity. What do you mean with natively? I would just use a standard IDE and this is a very basic feature if you develop any java application local.